# Angular 7 - Accessing to service returns undefined in observable

Tags: angular, service, observable

I'm working with a service that implements a global service called `AppService` which stores some global app configurations.

To begin with my question, I will post here some of my codes:

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

...

export function appLoadConfig(appService: AppService) {
  return () => appService.loadConfig();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appLoadConfig,
      deps: [ AppService ],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, ... } from '@angular/core';

...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {

  loadConfig(): Promise<any> { ... }

}
```

file.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from '../../app.service';
...

@Injectable()
export class FileService {

  filesChange: BehaviorSubject<FileNode[]> = new BehaviorSubject<FileNode[]>([]);

  constructor(
    private appService: AppService,
    private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  changeListType(types: string[]) {
    this._getAllFiles();
  }

  private _getAllFiles() {
    this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.appService.config.api}/api/files/`)
        .subscribe(this._publishData);
  }

  private _publishData(data: FileNode[]) {
    let nodeData: FileNode[] = [];
    data.forEach((n: any) => {
      const node = new FileNode(n);
      node.fullPath = `${this.appService.config.api}/uploads/${node.uri}`;
      nodeData.push(node);
    });
    this.filesChange.next(nodeData);
  }
}
```

When in a component I call the `changeListType` method from `file.service`, it retrieves the data, but the `_publishData` method shows that `this.appService`, used to build the `node.fullPath`, is undefined. If I change the call in the `_getAllFiles` method subscriber to this one:

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.appService.config.api}/api/files/`)
            .subscribe((data: any) => { this._publishData(data); });
```

The `appService` variable is not undefined anymore. Is this on purpose or it is a kind of bug/error related with scope variables? Or maybe I'm missing something within my code logic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got a problem with the scope of `this`:

In your second approach where you are not getting `appService` as undefined because you are referencing `_publishData` function from within an arrow function. Arrow functions doesn't create their own `this` and uses the this from it's outer scope. When `_publishData` function is being invoked in this case the `this` which it is referencing is the `this` of the component and not the function's `this`

Read more about arrow functions [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26).

If you are not using an arrow function and want to get the correct `this` for the subscriber function you will need to bind the `this`

You need to bind the correct this to `_publishData` function

```
  private _getAllFiles() {
    this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.appService.config.api}/api/files/`)
        .subscribe(this._publishData.bind(this));
  }
```

Comment: So it is more to a "bad logic" in my code than an error in Angular. I didn't have this error earlier when programming other apps, but I'm kinda new to Angular and I normally were using jQuery with single JS files for each page. Thanks for the clarification :) PS: You are missing a `)` closure in subscribe method.

Comment: Yes, it's not an Angular error but the issue of the context also referred to as this. And thanks for pointing the compiler issue, fixed it :) You can upvote it now :)